# QEMU DNS resolver not working (properly configured within the VM)

Tags: dns, qemu, resolve

From within the VM-image it is not possible to resolve addresses.

ping returns `ping: google.com: Name or service not known` and `resolvectl query google.com` `server or network returns error refused`.

The DNS service was properly configured as described in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-resolved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **host** systemd-resolved config was not correctly configured.

The file `/etc/resolv.conf` was empty. Using the stub method described in the arch wiki resolves the problem in the VM (`ln -rsf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`).

Not sure what caused the problem specifically, but I did not expect it to be caused by the host OS